# Numpy access to nD array values vetorized way

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Using numpy in python 3.9.

I have an array of images (480 images, each image of size 640x480).

I want to create an new image, where each line N of this image is the copy of the line N of the image #N in my array.

I can do it with loop :

```
for i, img in enumerate(image_array):
    new_image[i,:]=img[i,:)
```

Is there a way to do it with numpy using a vectorized way, since it is faster according the documentation ?

For context:
My array of images is initially created with this :

```
image_array = np.full((480,480,640,3), blank_image, np.uint8)
```

Each image in the array is then updated from a video stream.

I'm lost with the logic of np.diagonal, np.compress ...

Thank you

Edit:

Thanks to the first to answers :

```
idx = np.arange(len(image_array))
new_image = image_array[idx, idx, ...]
```

works as attented.

Comment: I cannot think of a way to this without a loop.  You're cutting across two dimensions here.  What you'd like to do is concatenate `x[0,0,:,:]` and `x[1,1,:,:]` and `x[2,2,:,:]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about smth like this (example for two images that are 2x2 pixels):
To adjust it to your needs you will have to change the argument of the 'arange' function.

```
import numpy as np

imgs = np.arange(2*2*2*3).reshape(2, 2, 2, 3)

print(f'images = \n{imgs}')

new_imgs = np.zeros((2, 2, 2, 3))

new_imgs[np.arange(2), np.arange(2), ...] = imgs[np.arange(2), np.arange(2), ...]

print(f'new_imgs = \n{new_imgs}')
```

output:

```
images = 
[[[[ 0  1  2]
   [ 3  4  5]]

  [[ 6  7  8]
   [ 9 10 11]]]


 [[[12 13 14]
   [15 16 17]]

  [[18 19 20]
   [21 22 23]]]]
new_imgs = 
[[[[ 0.  1.  2.]
   [ 3.  4.  5.]]

  [[ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]]]


 [[[ 0.  0.  0.]
   [ 0.  0.  0.]]

  [[18. 19. 20.]
   [21. 22. 23.]]]]
```

Comment: It produces the same output as my loop. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same indexing array in the first two dimensions.

```
idx = np.arange(len(image_array))
new_image = image_array[idx, idx, ...]
```

Comment: It produces the same output as my loop. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great, happy to help! Please remember to mark the answer as accepted. :-)